# Why do we need differential amplifier after Transimpedance amplifier?

Tags: differential, dc-offset, transimpedance

I am implementing the circuit published in AN3025 Transimpedance Amplifier Design as shown below. 
[image]

When I am simulating this circuit, a few questions come to mind:

Q1. Why do we need a differential amplifier in stage 2?
I think  this stage is to remove the offset voltage of the first stage. Am I right? But when I am simulating the above circuit using a single power supply, I am getting offset of 29mV. So what is the need of the difference amplifier? 
[image]

Q2. When I  used a dual power supply of 5V in the second stage, the offset voltage was completely removed.  However, this power supply of 5V is not recommended in the datasheet. But why is this happening?
[image]

Q3. When I have used a dual power supply of 2.5V then I got an offset of -2.47V. Why is this happening?

[image]

Q4. How do we completely remove the offset voltage?

Comment: Take a look at 4.1. Design Goals of that document.  It explains that this is an example that uses a single voltage rail, has no offset and does not invert the signal.  If you have multiple voltage rails and don't mind the signal being inverted, you could use a single opamp if you wanted.

Comment: Positive input of stage 1 has 1k||(1+10)k. So the reference is not vcc/2. Why is that?

Comment: In the datasheet I have seen that pin 7 is base. And why the emitter and collector is unused?

Comment: HI User 1850479, you are right that there is no offset in 4.1, but when I simulated this circuit as above I obtained an offset of 28.77mV. Why is that? can you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

With a single supply, the op amp's output can't quite reach the negative rail.

[image: Part of data sheet]

You could try reducing the load on the output by making R4=100k and R3=10k. I suspect you'd reduce that output voltage a bit.